# Could not convert category Name instead of category Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build Category wise subCategory in asp.net core 2.2, I successfully did it. but  I want to show Category Name instead of Category Id.
Here is my code:

Index.cshtml

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubCategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
           Category Name
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail text-danger" data-id="@item.Id">  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

When I Used `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)` instead of `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)` then It shows nothing.

Controller

```
public class SubCategoryController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public SubCategoryController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.SubCategory.ToList());
    }
}
```

Here is my output:
[image]

I don't understand how I show Category Name instead of Id. I am a beginner. Please help.

Comment: When you use `_db.SubCategory.ToList()`, you are only loading the subcategories, not their parent categories. You probably want something like `_db.SubCategory.Include(x => x.Category).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used  `_db.SubCategory.Include(x => x.Category).ToList()` instead of `_db.SubCategory.ToList()` then it's work as expected.